# doing some math in custom loss function in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, tensor

I create a keras sequential model with three dense layer and I just create a custom loss function as below:

```
def lossFunctionality(y_t, y_p):
    # 'y_t' shape is (bach_size, 500)
    # 'y_p' shape is (bach_size, 256) (output of last layer)
    # 'v' is np array of shape (500, 256)

    p = K.exp(K.dot(y_p, K.transpose(v)))
    sp = K.sum(p,axis=1)
    sp = K.expand_dims(sp, axis=1)
    sp = K.tile(sp,(1, len(v)))

    soft = p/sp
    soft=K.clip(soft, 0.0000001, 0.9999999)
    obj = K.categorical_crossentropy(soft, y_t)
    return obj
```

with this loss function everything goes fine.

but now suppose I have specefic 'v' array for each record in 'y_p' and I want to do line 5 of the code to have dot product of 'y_p' with record specefic 'v' array. in other words I have the number of bach_size of 'v' vectors that I want to product each record in 'y_p' to that specefic 'v' array. what I want is showing bellow:

```
def lossFunctionality(y_t, y_p):
    tempArray=[]
    for record in y_p:
        tempArray.append(K.exp(K.dot(record, K.transpose(v))))
    p=np.array(tempArray)
    sp = K.sum(p,axis=1)
    sp = K.expand_dims(sp, axis=1)
    sp = K.tile(sp,(1, len(v)))

    soft = p/sp
    soft=K.clip(soft, 0.0000001, 0.9999999)
    obj = K.categorical_crossentropy(soft, y_t)
    return obj
```

but I got error ''Tensor' object is not iterable.'
how can I implement my loss function in a right way
I realy appreciate your help

Comment: i think the error is in 3rd line of your code.. "for record in y_p"

Comment: you are right and I know the error is from that line. I want to know how can I implement this logic in a right way

Comment: I mean how can I iterate through Tensor object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really iterate a tensor or use lists, numpy arrays or so in a loss function.

Ideally, you must do everything with [backend](https://keras.io/backend/) functions, which work properly with tensors.

If I undesrtood it correctly, what you need is a `batch_dot` function, perhaps in association with `permute_dimensions` if you really need to transpose "v".

I'm assuming you have a list of "v" vectors, right? I'll answer it as if "v" in my code were a numpy array shaped as `(batch_size, 500, 256)`.

```
import keras.backend as K

--------------

#transform v in a tensor
vTens = K.variable(v) #maybe having vTens already instanced and transposed outside the loss function would result in better performance (if it's constant)   

#transposing v without changing the batch dimension
vTrans = K.permute_dimensions(vTens,(0,2,1)) 

#doing a batch dot
dotResult = K.batch_dot(y_p,vTrans,axes=[1,2])
```

In the `batch_dot`, axes 1 and 2 were considered, while axis 0 is the batch size and will be kept untouched.

### Important remark on your function:

You won't be able to have `y_p` and `y_t` with different dimensions. That's simply unacceptable. Your model predictions must have the exact same shape as your true values.

An error will certainly appear in the `fit` method (or any other training method) telling you that your dimensions mismatch.

You do need to have a layer to transform your output **before** reaching the loss function, so `y_p` and `y_t` have the same dimensions.

For that, use a [LambdaLayer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda)

```
model.add(LambdaLayer(transformOutput, output_shape=(500,))
```

Where `transformOutput` is the function you described before, also working with tensors.

```
def transformOutput(x):
    #transform v in a tensor
    vTens = K.variable(v) #maybe having vTens already instanced and transposed outside the loss function would result in better performance (if it's constant)   

    #transposing v without changing the batch dimension
    vTrans = K.permute_dimensions(vTens,(0,2,1)) 

    #doing a batch dot
    return K.batch_dot(x,vTrans,axes=[1,2])
```

Comment: I ran your solution. Suppose I have bach_size=2 then I got this error: 'Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,256], [2,256,500].'

Comment: I just make it work by adding this line:


        x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=K.ndim(x) if 1 == K.ndim(x) - 1 else K.ndim(x))    and remove the transpose line.